# How to iterate all the points on curves

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, iteration

I plot curves by

```
ContourPlot[x^2 y + x y^2 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

It shows three curves on the `(x,y)` plane, but now my question is how to iterate all the points on the curves, the iterative equation is complex (**nonlinear**), for example, `x = x+y*x, and y = x*y+y^2`.

I have an idea, solve `x^2 y + x y^2 == 1` and get `(x,y)`, then plot it by `ParametricPlot` one by one, but it will be tedious (as it is nonlinear, so solve it is difficult sometimes). Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** An alternative approach using `BSplineFunction`:

```
ClearAll[tr, iter]

tr = {# + #2 #, # #2 + #2^2} & @@@ # &;

iter = Normal[#] /. Line -> (Line[tr[BSplineFunction[#] /@ Subdivide[50]]] &) &;
```

***Examples:***

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2 y + x y^2 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];

NestList[iter, cp, 3]
```

[image]

```
NestList[Show[iter @ #, PlotRange -> All] &, cp, 3]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[tr, iterate]

tr = {# + #2 #, # #2 + #2^2} & @@@ # &;
iterate = MapAt[tr, #, {1, 1, 1}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2 y + x y^2 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];

NestList[iterate, cp, 3]
```

[image]

```
NestList[Show[iterate @ #, PlotRange -> All] &, cp, 3]
```

[image]

**Note:** In version 11.3 replace `{1, 1, 1}` with `{1, 1}` in `MapAt[...]`.

Comment: Very interesting! Trying to reproduce your results I get message `Plus is not a Graphics primitive or directive.` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, in v12.1 we need  `{1,1,1}` in the last argument of `MapAt`  to get the coordinates of  `GraphicsComplex`. In version 11.3 `{1,1}` works,

Comment: How simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

There are two solutions

```
sol = Solve[x^2 y + x y^2 == 1, y] // Simplify

(* {{y -> -((x^(3/2) + Sqrt[4 + x^3])/(2 Sqrt[x]))}, {y -> -(x/2) + Sqrt[
    4 + x^3]/(2 Sqrt[x])}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[y /. sol], {x, -10, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.75, .75}]]
```

[image]